# Count based on other csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df with two columns called 'MovieName' and 'Actors'. It looks like:

```
MovieName    Actors
lights out   Maria Bello
legend       Tom Hardy*Emily Browning*Christopher Eccleston*David Thewlis
```

Please note that different actor names are separated by '*'. I have another csv file called gender.csv which has the gender of all actors based on their first names. gender.csv looks like -

```
ActorName    Gender
Tom          male
Emily        female
Christopher  male
```

I want to add two columns in my dataframe 'female_actors' and 'male_actors' which contains the count of female and male actors in that particular movie respectively.

How do I achieve this task using both df and gender.csv in pandas?

Please note that -

1. If particular name isn't present in gender.csv, don't count it in the total.
2. If there is just one actor in a movie, and it isn't present in gender.csv, then  it's count should be zero.

Result of above example should be -

```
MovieName    Actors      male_actors    female_actors
lights out   Maria Bello    0              0
legend       Tom Hardy*Emily Browning*Christopher Eccleston*David Thewlis    2    1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'MovieName': ['lights out', 'legend'], 'Actors':['Maria Bello', 'Tom Hardy*Emily Browning*Christopher Eccleston*David Thewlis']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ActorName': ['Tom', 'Emily', 'Christopher'], 'Gender':['male', 'female', 'male']})


def func(actors, gender):
    actors = [act.split()[0] for act in actors.split('*')]      
    n_gender = df2.Gender[df2.Gender==gender][df2.ActorName.isin(actors)].count()
    return n_gender

df1['male_actors'] = df1.Actors.apply(lambda x: func(x, 'male'))
df1['female_actors'] = df1.Actors.apply(lambda x: func(x, 'female'))

df1.to_csv('res.csv', index=False)
print df1
```

Output

```
Actors,MovieName,male_actors,female_actors
Maria Bello,lights out,0,0
Tom Hardy*Emily Browning*Christopher Eccleston*David Thewlis,legend,2,1
```

Comment: Nice. Can we return male and female count at the same time from the function and store it as a row?

Comment: @qmaruf   It throws an error. AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'   Is it because there are some NaN values?

Comment: @Dreamer I think so. You should process data appropriately.

Comment: @qmaruf There are no NaN values. Can you suggest me a possible solution to this problem. Your code is amazing!

Comment: I am using split in actorname column. Please make sure that, that column only contains string type data.

Comment: @qmaruf IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You should print the `actors` value in `func` and debug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129197/discussion-between-dreamer-and-qmaruf).